# Xamarin - MonoDevelop _ Impossible to creat a solution for "Mono for Android"

Tags: android, macos, exception, monodevelop, osx-lion

I followed the steps to install MonoDevelop for Android on Mac OSX Lion 10.7 thanks to this link [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Mac).
Before, I have done the same thing for MonoDevelop for IOS, and it works.
But now with MonoDevelop for Android I get an exception, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

It could be nice if someone could help me ?

Thanks a lot.

*exception:*

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> MonoDevelop.Core.UserException: Mono for Android is not installed
  at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidProject.ThrowIfNotInstalled () [0x0002d] in /private/tmp/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDroidProject.cs:58 
  at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidProject.Init () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDroidProject.cs:222 
  at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x0001b] in /private/tmp/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDroidProject.cs:183 
  at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidProjectBinding.CreateProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDroidProjectBinding.cs:40 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.CreateProject (System.String type, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00033] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectService.cs:498 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.CreateItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x00036] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/ProjectDescriptor.cs:111 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectTemplate.HasItemFeatures (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolder parentFolder, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation cinfo) [0x0000e] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/ProjectTemplate.cs:302 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.SelectedIndexChange (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x000e3] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:474 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog+TemplateView.m__3A (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:678 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000d5] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:226 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000eb] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:234 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:96 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x000bf] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:408 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00018] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System/MulticastDelegate.cs:70 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:382 
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re install Mono for Andoid 1.2.0 trial and now it works.

> Hi,
>
> There are actually two issues here. The first one is that you should
>   actually have been shown a much more informative error dialog attached
>   to this email. I've fixed this issue so in future releases of
>   MonoDevelop you will no longer get that unintelligible stacktrace.
>   Apologies for this.
>
> Secondly, when you get this error, it means that Mono for Android has
>   not been installed correctly and cannot be found. Can you confirm that
>   you've installed Mono for Andoid 1.2.0 trial or full edition? To
>   verify it's in the standard location, you should find the directory at
>   /Developer/MonoAndroid on your filesystem. If it's not there, then
>   something has gone wrong with the installation. In that case, i'd
>   recommend reinstalling Mono for Android again and verifying if it is
>   installed to that location.
>
> Do let us know if that resolves the issue for you. If it doesn't, we
>   might need to get some more information in order to figure out exactly
>   what has gone wrong.
>
> Thanks, Alan